# SQL query to retrieve users combining two meta keys and values from wp_usermeta

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I've got a Wordpress site where users can register as teachers or students of different languages.

I'm now trying to search all the users registered as **French teachers** via phpMyAdmin but I can't figure out which query I should use.

A user registered as a teacher has a meta_value of `a:1:{s:16:"cliente_profesor";b:1;}` for the meta_key `wp_capabilities`.

And if he/she teaches French she/he has a meta_value of `2` for the meta_key `idioma_registro`.

So this is how I tried to combine that info in my query:

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE (`meta_key` LIKE 'idioma_registro' AND `meta_value` LIKE '2') AND (`meta_key` LIKE 'wp_capabilities' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'a:1:{s:16:"cliente_profesor";b:1;}');
```

The result when running the query was '0' but I know that there are over 20000 French teachers registered on the site. So I'm doing something wrong with this query.

Thanks in advance for any help you could offer me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution in Stackexchange [thanks to Brent](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116426/select-user-by-joining-multiple-meta-value-results).

Here is the code I was looking for:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.display_name
FROM wp_users AS u
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS um1 ON u.ID = um1.user_id
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS um2 ON u.ID = um2.user_id
WHERE  um1.meta_key = 'idioma_registro' AND um1.meta_value = '2'
AND um2.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND um2.meta_value = 'a:1:{s:16:"cliente_profesor";b:1;}'
```

I hope this helps more people!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE (`meta_key` LIKE 'idioma_registro' AND `meta_value` LIKE '2') 
OR (`meta_key` LIKE 'wp_capabilities' AND `meta_value` LIKE 'a:1:{s:16:"cliente_profesor";b:1;}')
```

Note: you cannot use `AND`query because `idioma_registro` and `wp_capabilities` not in same row. There are different row.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it and it didn't give me the result I was looking for, sorry. But I found a solution I'm posting here now.